# How to make getJSON code cleaner looking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Is there a way to rewrite the following code so that it looks cleaner. Maybe using `await`? 
I really don't like the idea of having nested functions, but I need to wait till I get both .json files loaded before my app can start...

Any idea how to clean this up?

```
 $.getJSON('myFile1.json', function(data) {
      var myFile = data;
      $.getJSON('myFile2.json', function(data) {
          var myFile2 = data;
          // Do stuff. 
          return 0;
      });
      return 0;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more helpful for this type of questions

Comment: Why bother with `var myFile = data`? Just name the parameter `myFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
var getJson1 = $.getJSON('myFile1.json');
var getJson2 = $.getJSON('myFile2.json');
$.when(getJson1, getJson2).done(function(data1, data2){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want promises, my man.

[Native promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[Jquery promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Put the return values of `getJSON` in an array. Pass that to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). When it resolves (which will be when both `getJSON` promises have resolved), it will have an array with all the data in it.

```js
var urls = ["https://api.domainsdb.info/search?query=microsoft", "https://api.domainsdb.info/search?query=google"];

Promise.all([
  $.getJSON(urls[0]),
  $.getJSON(urls[1])
]).then((data) => console.log({
  "Total Microsoft domains": data[0].total,
  "Total Google domains": data[1].total,
  "Grand total": data[0].total + data[1].total
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

getJSON returns a promise https://api.jquery.com/promise/.  So this sort of thing works:

```
var firstPromise = $.getJSON('myFile1.json');
var secondPromise = $.getJSON('myFile2.json');

$.when(firstPromise, secondPromise).done(function(firstData, secondData) {
  // do something
});
```